# Datatable server-side script

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, server-side

I've found this piece of code which looks to work for some people,

```
$dataArr['aaData'] = Array();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
$r = Array();
foreach($row as $key=>$value){
    $r[] = "$key $value";
}
$dataArr['aaData'][] = $r;} 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($dataArr);
/* The output will be of the form, 
{"aaData": [ [
[
   "colname data"
   ...
],
 ] */
```

but I get an error " Table id =datos Invalid json response.

My Datatable columns do not have the same name as my db columns, and I'm not sure how to handle that.
Here is my js :

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
function getCpAndVille(data, type, dataToSet) {
return data.cp + " " + data.ville;
}
$('#datos').dataTable({
 "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
 "bProcessing": true,
"sAjaxSource": 'ajx/datatable_process_search.php',
"aoColumnDefs": [
                  { "sName": "Réf.", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
                  { "sName": "Poste", "aTargets": [ 1 ] },
                  { "sName": "Type de contrat", "aTargets": [ 2 ] },
                  { "sName": "Date de publication", "aTargets": [ 3 ]},
                  { "sName": "Lieu", "aTargets": [ 4 ], "mData": getCpAndVille  },
                  { "sName": "Descriptif", "aTargets": [ 5 ] }
                ],
```

Can someone tell me the right php code I should use, please, because it's quite hard to find it, and I don't understand the example given in http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Thanks in advance.

Console Network --> {"aaData":[["job_id 9261","job_intitule Assistant Achats","job_contrat Int\u00e9rim","job_date_insertion 2015-02-20","cp 06110","job_ville 19"], and so on...

Comment: I'm using this class to build my data, maybe it help you: [https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php)

Comment: Thanks for this. 
But I don't have a clue of how to use this class as my $query involves a JOIN . and I don't know how to make their example fit to my conditions....

Comment: Please, post the `json` that you get from `json_encode($dataArr);`

Comment: Here is one example of a valid json response to build your table: [https://gist.github.com/victor0402/5e06b594ecceed226dfb](https://gist.github.com/victor0402/5e06b594ecceed226dfb)

Comment: I've edited my 1st post, at the bottom you'll find the content of what I get in Network, when I click on datatable_process_search.php. 
Yes I've seen what my array is supposed to look like but I don't know who to get to this point.  I can remove $key from $r[], ok, but for the rest, I don't know...  :) Thanks

Comment: So, the main problem is in your json response, you need to parse your array in the right format. Also, apparently your javascript code is using an older version of data-tables, just looking the javascript code from the example that you have posted, there are a lot of differences. So use the [right docs](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: I've found a piece of code here [link](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21811/solution-serverside-using-join-pdo-php)
which looks like to be the answer for the server-side php pdo script, with mysql JOIN.
Great !
However as I don't know MVC coding, I'm unable to repair/deal with
`Fatal error: Class '__CLASS' not found in C:\wamp\www\xx\xx\ajx\datatables.class.php on line 9 `

My js : `$('#datos').dataTable({
  "sAjaxSource": 'ajx/instance.php',`  Is is right? 

PS - I put all of the files stated in the link, in my ajx folder --
Anticipate Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for a serverside script including JOIN table

https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/467455/convert-datatables-to-server-side-processing